# 2007 Honda Civic warning lights all on and stiff steering wheel?

Tags: honda, civic, steering, hybrid, warning-light

I was trying to diagnose my AC compressor issue and was pulling some of the circuits and fuses to see if they possibly went bad.

Thankfully I identified the problem being the blower motor not running but in the process created another problem ... All my lights are on including brakes, engine, airbag etc ... and also my 'D' light is flashing (I know there's nothing wrong with the transmission). I disconnected the battery and reconnected with no avail. I tried driving it but the steering wheel is really stiff and almost locked-up.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using a digital multimeter, see what the alternator output is while the engine is running.

Comment: Ran the test and getting 12V. So the alternator seems fine. Could it be one of circuits or switches I removed causing this..?

Comment: No. If you're only getting 12v at the alternator, it's not good. It should be about 13.5-14.1vdc while the engine is running. Check the voltage of the battery without the engine running and I'll bet it's about the same as with it running.

Comment: I think you're right. Just unsure how this would lock-up my steering and my 'D' gear light to start blinking......Any ideas?

Comment: Does  your Honda use an electric or an electromechanical power steering unit? Not sure why it would do either, but there is something wrong with the alternator, so get it fixed, whatever the issue is, and see if it fixes the other stuff as well.

Comment: electromagnetically power steering. I still think I might've shorted or burned one of the circuits......

Comment: You might have fried a fuse, but I doubt you've burned out the circuits beyond that.

Comment: The test I did was actually for the battery not the alternator. I assumed  since the battery is averaging 12V, it was being charged by the alternator......I just realized I'm working on a hybrid thus no alternator......damn.....Should've noticed it from the get go.......Thanks for the help but I'm SOL it seems on this as I don't work on hybrids

Comment: so I finally got the problem fixed......turns out ABS/VSA 10A fuse blew causing the gauge clusters coming on and causing steering lock-up. Thought I'd let you know; didn't want to leave you hanging ;)

Comment: Well, you can always answer your own question, either that or I can throw an answer out there. If there isn't an "answer", that's what leaves us hanging :o)

Comment: I think if you can put that in an answer form, It'll help the next guy who is having this same issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(NOTE: Pulling from comments)

It seems to me you probably blew a fuse while doing what you did. Check all of them to ensure they're good.